# How To Get Last Record with Multiple Criteria in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm consistently adding records from Google Forms, and I need to copy the results into a different sheet in the spreadsheet.

I have two examples from the image (to be clear.)

1. I need to copy the last record that matches "New York" "Reptiles" that have the Status of "In Transit."

   The result should be "5"
2. I need to copy the last record that matches "California" "Animals" that have the Status of "Arrived."

   The result should be "70"

I can't thank you enough for your feedback! You'll bring some sanity to me! In the event, you have time to explain why I would sincerely love it.

[image: Google Sheets Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY({A1:E}, "select Col3 
                where Col1='New York' 
                  and Col5='In Transit'  
                offset "&COUNTA(QUERY({A1:E}, "select Col3 
                                               where Col1='New York' 
                                                 and Col5='In Transit'", 0))-1, 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY({A1:E}, "select Col2 
                where Col1='California' 
                  and Col5='Arrived'  
                offset "&COUNTA(QUERY({A1:E}, "select Col2 
                                               where Col1='California' 
                                                 and Col5='Arrived'", 0))-1, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=index(query(sort(A:E,Row(A:E),0),"where Col1='New York' and Col5='In Transit' limit 1"),1,match("Reptiles",1:1,0))
```

and

```
=index(query(sort(A:E,Row(A:E),0),"where Col1='California' and Col5='Arrived' limit 1"),1,match("Animals",1:1,0))
```

where your selections are hard coded, since you have not specified where to find your choices.